# Insertion Of data into temp table

Tags: t-sql, sybase, dbvisualizer

I am using sybase database and i use DB visulazier, I  have two tables one of the table has 30 million and other table has 3 million which has archive data of the first table. Both the tables grow by date, i mean every day we get records into the table. 
I am creating a temp table and inserting both the tables into the temp tables and the insertion takes a lot of time so times it blows off the software.

i get errors: alter table size or remove temp tables from sys logs.

can i get any help how to improve the performance.???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, temprory tables shouldn't be used for inserting  millions of data. it would fill tempdb.

to avoid logs filling, insert data in small batches, may be 1000-10000 rows at a time.

curious to know why are adding this much records in temp table ?

Comment: i am migrating the database, can you give me an example of how to do in batches?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify, I'll assume you are talking about SAP Sybase ASE.  ASE inlcudes many options for improving tempdb performance.  I would suggest you take a look at the Performance and Tuning documentation, specifically the area on Temporary Databases.

[Performance and Tuning Series: Physical Database Tuning - Temporary Databases](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00841.1502/html/phys_tune/X94507.htm)